# Getting gibberish from imagecopy function,

Tags: php

Hia, I have just made the code:

```
<?php
$ur = $user['Skin'];

$filename = "img/Skins/" . $ur;
list($w, $h, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
$img = imagecreatefrompng($filename); 
$src_im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
$src_x = '30';   // begin x
$src_y = '45';   // begin y
$src_w = '40'; // width
$src_h = '35'; // height
$dst_x = '0';   // destination x
$dst_y = '0';   // destination y

$dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
$white = imagecolorallocate($dst_im, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($dst_im, 0, 0, $white);

imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

?>
<img src="<?php print_r(imagepng($dst_im)); ?>"/>
```

What this is supposed to do is get the image "Skin" and cut out the head, so my image:

```
<img src="<?php print_r(imagepng($dst_im)); ?>"/>
```

Should only be the head of the skin. However, I am being given this gibberish:

> ù¬åä) BðÔ€ÛÂ~Í‹P3£Œ´¶ÛÛ A†YEUkÌ¡èæ_Ê!ÊÔgò
> s“Û¤ÇC‚MŒ+‰?>¡·Ñ[ïªWf™.œsá¸œ3€@á¦~vþf ŒÀì¢ ª}à9¹#åIÄ‰ê•¡
> èˆÀî”Ûw¥@ù"¢¢™áHªUúÝ¸÷ÉÇYÿ®šGÅçÇ˜îwqžˆ³ýÏJ
> ÕKSêô¯Tis“†Ã¡í©ÈK‡}G:Xqt×ÓIJEpT,úŽ¿ƒ~¼lÞÈ­Ú6]_Óœ>®çqÿNÏ‘çqWŠjš-…(—=g¿ÁŸÍgæ+ùB¹R©ÖwÜ¸þn¤:C‰õØËüÛïÝ±I¸°\ÉÌ[%«V³7ÞÕM¾Í>[ké·IEND®B`‚1"/>

What should I do, and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use your php script as the `src` attribute of you `<img>` tag:

**yourScript.php**

```
...

$im = imagepng($dst_im);

header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

**Markup**

```
<img src="yourScript.php" alt="Some alt text">
```

Answer (score 1):

@moonwave99 answer is correct.
But if you want to get image base64 data from imagecopy function here is a simple example for what I've done.

I've used it to create watermarks on picture.

```
<?php
function image_data_base64() {
    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('picture.png');
    imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - imagesx($stamp) - 15, 15, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
    ob_start();
        imagepng($im);
        $image_data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return base64_encode($image_data);
}
?>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo image_data_base64(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just output an image like that. That's the data of the image. You can write to file and use the corresponding URI, or you can do this

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(imagepng($dst_im)); ?>" />
```

Comment: That gives me this (in chrome inspect element): <img src="data:image/png;base64,MQ=="> - which didn't really help.

Comment: i'd expect a the string to be a little longer than that... MQ== is equal to 1, which could be a true. Hmm...

Comment: That was the output from your original, this is what I get for your updated: <img src="data:image/png;base64,‰PNG .. blah blah

Comment: which looks right. How are you executing this file to show the image? Is it as moonwave99 is thinking?